# How can I merge ESP32 Classic Webcamera Server classic template with this auth token login page explain in this tutorial from Renzo Mischianti?

Tags: html, authentication, server, arduino-esp32

I would like integrate auth token AsyncWebServer explained in this [tutorial](https://mischianti.org/web-server-with-esp8266-and-esp32-manage-security-and-authentication-4/) with classic camera web server for esp32?
I can't figure out how to combine them, but I tried...

Using the routing of authentication tutorial, I can visualize login page then redirect to index.html page that I put in Folder Data, but the /status and /command of app_httpd.cpp.

````
#define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER // Has PSRAM
    #include "esp_camera.h"
    #include <WiFi.h>
    #include <WebServer.h>
    #include <SPIFFS.h>
    #include "Arduino.h"
    #include "camera_pins.h"
    #include <AsyncTCP.h>
    #include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
    #include "mbedtls/md.h"
    #include "camera_index.h"



    const char* ssid = "ssid";
    const char* password = "pass";

    const char* www_username = "admin";
    const char* www_password = "admin";

         // Set web server port number to 80
    AsyncWebServer httpServer(80);
 
    void serverRouting();
    void startCameraServer();

    // Declare external function from app_httpd.cpp
    extern void startCameraServer();
    extern void serialDump();

    bool is_authenticated(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    Serial.println("Enter is_authenticated");
    if (request->hasHeader("Cookie")) {
        Serial.print("Found cookie: ");
        String cookie = request->header("Cookie");
        Serial.println(cookie);
 
        String token = sha1(String(www_username) + ":" +
                String(www_password) + ":" +
                request->client()->remoteIP().toString());
    //  token = sha1(token);
 
        if (cookie.indexOf("ESPSESSIONID=" + token) != -1) {
            Serial.println("Authentication Successful");
            return true;
        }
    }
    Serial.println("Authentication Failed");
    return false;
    }

    String sha1(String payloadStr){
    const char *payload = payloadStr.c_str();
 
    int size = 20;
 
    byte shaResult[size];
 
    mbedtls_md_context_t ctx;
    mbedtls_md_type_t md_type = MBEDTLS_MD_SHA1;
 
    const size_t payloadLength = strlen(payload);
 
    mbedtls_md_init(&ctx);
    mbedtls_md_setup(&ctx, mbedtls_md_info_from_type(md_type), 0);
    mbedtls_md_starts(&ctx);
    mbedtls_md_update(&ctx, (const unsigned char *) payload, payloadLength);
    mbedtls_md_finish(&ctx, shaResult);
    mbedtls_md_free(&ctx);
 
    String hashStr = "";
 
    for(uint16_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        String hex = String(shaResult[i], HEX);
        if(hex.length() < 2) {
            hex = "0" + hex;
        }
        hashStr += hex;
    }
 
    return hashStr;
    }
 
    void setup(void) {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    Serial.println("");
    
    //Configurazione Camera
    camera_config_t config;
    config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
    config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
    config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_sccb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_sccb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
    config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
    config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;
    config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG; // for streaming
    //config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_RGB565; // for face detection/recognition
    config.grab_mode = CAMERA_GRAB_WHEN_EMPTY;
    config.fb_location = CAMERA_FB_IN_PSRAM;
    config.jpeg_quality = 12;
    config.fb_count = 1;
  
    // if PSRAM IC present, init with UXGA resolution and higher JPEG quality
    //                      for larger pre-allocated frame buffer.
    if(config.pixel_format == PIXFORMAT_JPEG){
    if(psramFound()){
      config.jpeg_quality = 10;
      config.fb_count = 2;
      config.grab_mode = CAMERA_GRAB_LATEST;
    } else {
      // Limit the frame size when PSRAM is not available
      config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
      config.fb_location = CAMERA_FB_IN_DRAM;
    }
    } else {
    // Best option for face detection/recognition
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_240X240;
    #if CONFIG_IDF_TARGET_ESP32S3
    config.fb_count = 2;
    #endif
    }

  #if defined(CAMERA_MODEL_ESP_EYE)
  pinMode(13, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(14, INPUT_PULLUP);
  #endif

  // camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }

  sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
  // initial sensors are flipped vertically and colors are a bit saturated
  if (s->id.PID == OV3660_PID) {
    s->set_vflip(s, 1); // flip it back
    s->set_brightness(s, 1); // up the brightness just a bit
    s->set_saturation(s, -2); // lower the saturation
  }
  // drop down frame size for higher initial frame rate
  if(config.pixel_format == PIXFORMAT_JPEG){
    s->set_framesize(s, FRAMESIZE_QVGA);
  }

  #if defined(CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_WIDE) || defined(CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_ESP32CAM)
  s->set_vflip(s, 1);
  s->set_hmirror(s, 1);
  #endif

  #if defined(CAMERA_MODEL_ESP32S3_EYE)
  s->set_vflip(s, 1);
  #endif

  // Setup LED FLash if LED pin is defined in camera_pins.h
  #if defined(LED_GPIO_NUM)
  setupLedFlash(LED_GPIO_NUM);
  #endif


 
    // Connessione
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }
 
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("Connected to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
 
    Serial.print(F("Inizializing FS..."));
    if (SPIFFS.begin()) {
        Serial.println(F("done."));
    } else {
        Serial.println(F("fail."));
    }
 
    Serial.println("Set routing for http server!");
    
    serverRouting();
    startCameraServer();
    httpServer.begin();
    Serial.println("Fatto!");
             




    Serial.println("HTTP server started");
    }
 
    void loop(void){
 
    }
     //Gestione Login Page
    String getContentType(String filename) {
    if (filename.endsWith(F(".htm"))) return F("text/html");
    else if (filename.endsWith(F(".html"))) return F("text/html");
    else if (filename.endsWith(F(".css"))) return F("text/css");
    else if (filename.endsWith(F(".js"))) return F("application/javascript");
    else if (filename.endsWith(F(".json"))) return F("application/json");
    else if (filename.endsWith(F(".png"))) return F("image/png");
    else if (filename.endsWith(F(".gif"))) return F("image/gif");
    else if (filename.endsWith(F(".jpg"))) return F("image/jpeg");
    else if (filename.endsWith(F(".jpeg"))) return F("image/jpeg");
    else if (filename.endsWith(F(".ico"))) return F("image/x-icon");
    else if (filename.endsWith(F(".xml"))) return F("text/xml");
    else if (filename.endsWith(F(".pdf"))) return F("application/x-pdf");
    else if (filename.endsWith(F(".zip"))) return F("application/x-zip");
    else if (filename.endsWith(F(".gz"))) return F("application/x-gzip");
    return F("text/plain");
     }
 
    bool handleFileRead(AsyncWebServerRequest *request, String path) {
    Serial.print(F("handleFileRead: "));
    Serial.println(path);
 
    if (!is_authenticated(request)) {
        Serial.println(F("Go on not login!"));
        path = "/login.html";
    } else {
    if (path.endsWith("/")) path += F("index.html");

     //startCameraServer();
      // If a folder is requested, send the index file
      }    
      String contentType = getContentType(path);              // Get the MIME type
      String pathWithGz = path + F(".gz");
      if(SPIFFS.exists(pathWithGz) || SPIFFS.exists(path)){     // If the file exists, either as a      compressed archive, or normal
        bool gzipped = false;
 
        if(SPIFFS.exists(pathWithGz)) {                         // If there's a compressed version  available
          path += F(".gz");                                     // Use the compressed version
          gzipped = true;
      
        }
        AsyncWebServerResponse *response = request->beginResponse(SPIFFS, path, contentType);
        if (gzipped){
            response->addHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        }
        Serial.print("Real file path: ");
        Serial.println(path);
 
        request->send(response);

        return true;
      }
    Serial.println(String(F("\tFile Not Found: ")) + path);
    return false;                     // If the file doesn't exist, return false
    }
 
    void handleNotFound(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
      String message = "File Not Found\n\n";
      message += "URI: ";
      message += request->url();
      message += "\nMethod: ";
      message += (request->method() == HTTP_GET) ? "GET" : "POST";
      message += "\nArguments: ";
      message += request->args();
      message += "\n";
 
      for (uint8_t i = 0; i < request->args(); i++) {
      message += " " + request->argName(i) + ": " + request->arg(i) + "\n";
      }
 
      request->send(404, "text/plain", message);
    }
 
    void handleLogin(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    Serial.println("Handle login");
    String msg;
    if (request->hasHeader("Cookie")) {
        // Print cookies
        Serial.print("Found cookie: ");
        String cookie = request->header("Cookie");
        Serial.println(cookie);
    }
 
    if (request->hasArg("username") && request->hasArg("password")) {
        Serial.print("Found parameter: ");
 
        if (request->arg("username") == String(www_username) && request->arg("password") ==         String(www_password)) {
            AsyncWebServerResponse *response = request->beginResponse(301); //Sends 301 redirect
 
            response->addHeader("Location", "/");
            response->addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
 
            String token = sha1(String(www_username) + ":" + String(www_password) + ":" +     request->client()->remoteIP().toString());
            Serial.print("Token: ");
            Serial.println(token);
            response->addHeader("Set-Cookie", "ESPSESSIONID=" + token);
 
            request->send(response);
            Serial.println("Log in Successful");
            return;
        }
        msg = "Wrong username/password! try again.";
        Serial.println("Log in Failed");
        AsyncWebServerResponse *response = request->beginResponse(301); //Sends 301 redirect
 
        response->addHeader("Location", "/login.html?msg=" + msg);
        response->addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        request->send(response);
        return;
        }
}
 
    /**
     * Manage logout (simply remove correct token and redirect to login form)
     */
    void handleLogout(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    Serial.println("Disconnection");
    AsyncWebServerResponse *response = request->beginResponse(301); //Sends 301 redirect
 
    response->addHeader("Location", "/login.html?msg=User disconnected");
    response->addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response->addHeader("Set-Cookie", "ESPSESSIONID=0");
    request->send(response);
    return;
    }
    //Check if header is present and correct

    void serverRouting() {
    // External rest end point (out of authentication)

    httpServer.on("/login", HTTP_POST, handleLogin);
    httpServer.on("/logout", HTTP_GET, handleLogout);
  


 
    Serial.println(F("Go on not found!"));
    httpServer.onNotFound([](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {               // If the client requests any URI
                Serial.println(F("On not found"));
                if (!handleFileRead(request, request->url())){                  // send it if it exists
                    handleNotFound(request); // otherwise, respond with a 404 (Not Found) error
                }
            });
 
    Serial.println(F("Set cache!"));
    // Serve a file with no cache so every tile It's downloaded
    httpServer.serveStatic("/configuration.json", SPIFFS, "/configuration.json", "no-cache, no-        store, must-revalidate");
    // Server all other page with long cache so browser chaching they
    // Comment this line for esp8266
    httpServer.serveStatic("/", SPIFFS, "/", "max-age=31536000");
    }
    ```
````

Comment: I help you correct some typos and format your text, but it is your responsibility to indent your code correctly. Your code in current make it hard to follow the logic. You also seem to have an unfinished sentence to describe the problem you are facing.